# How to search for a specific string in .c file using Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have to search for a specific string in a generated `.c` file, once the string is matched. Rest of the function should be imported into an Excel sheet. 
Example:

```
FUNCTION(int, char) import_speed_information(ptr(int, char, char) Data) /* current speed */
{
    /* Dont care */
}
```

string to be searched : `FUNCTION(int, char)`

Rest of the information in that line as shown below

```
"import_speed_information(ptr(int, char, char) Data)"
```

Has to be copied in excel sheet in a Tabular format (note: comments should be excluded).

How to proceed?

Comment: are you familiar with regular expressions?

Comment: You should edit your post and use the code formatting button.

Comment: Yes , iam familiar with regular expression.